# Show every percentage with 4 decimals

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a sub.
I wanted to display every percentage number in a column with 4 decimals.

I tried it like this:

```
Sub test()

 Set bereich = Range("J1:J100")

 For Each Cell In bereich
    If Zelle = "0.00%" Then NumberFormat = "0.0000%"

 Next Cell

 End Sub
```

But it doesnt work.
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set the formatting of the cell to have 4 decimal points? Format Cells... -> Number -> Percentage -> Decimals Places: 4

Comment: Cell.NumberFormat = "0.0000%" ?

Comment: Because Im building a sheet to format data, so that I can just copy in the Data and the get formated like how I need them. And in this column are also other numbers. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Sub test()

Dim bereich As Range, Cell As Range

Set bereich = Range("J1:J100")

For Each Cell In bereich
   If Cell.NumberFormat = "0%" Then Cell.NumberFormat = "0.0000%"
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: @DaZn you'rw welcome :) now comes your part where you mark this as "ANSWER" by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer

Comment: I did :) but I got another problem, when I insert my data, the cells the percentage numbers are formated "standard" and not as percentage. Can you fix it, maybe like "If "##.##%" Then cell.numberFormat = "0.0000%"

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9WVV.jpg)

it looks like this when I insert the data. And I wanna find every "%" in this column and when there is one I wanna show the same number but with four decimals. If there are already four decimals, it should not add more.